# Catching exceptions for "INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" workaround in ZF

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, exception, mysql-error-1062

`ZF 1.9.5` here. Someone suggested catching exceptions to emulate `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` when using Zend_Db_Table.

Currently, I'm getting

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'i7dd30253497cfc0539d7c5830a926f7d' for key 'ukey'`

..when using

```
$orderRow = $this->createRow();
$orderRow->ukey = $ukey;
$orderRow->save();
```

So, I want to catch that bugger with `try / catch`. On exception `update` , else `insert`.
But I don't know what to catch. `Zend_Db_Exception`? `PDOException`? `Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception`? I've tried several, but I don't think I got it.

---

Later edit.
This worked for me:

```
        try {
            $orderRow = $this->createRow();
            $orderRow->ukey = $ukey;
            $orderRow->$stepCol = time();
            $orderRow->save();
        } catch (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception $e) {
            // on UNIQUE error, update
            if ($e->getCode() == 23000) {
                $orderRow = $this->fetchRow($this->select()->where('ukey = ?', $ukey));
                $orderRow->$stepCol = time();
                $orderRow->save();
            }
        }
```

Comment: if the code is not 2300 you should probably re-throw the exception so you don't miss some other kind of error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just look what exception is getting thrown like this:

```
try {
    // query
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump(get_class($e));
}
```

That should tell you what kind of exception you need to catch because "Exception" will catch every type of exception, be it a ZF exception or a PDO exception or something completely different

Comment: `Zend_Db_Statement_Exception`. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

**It will throw a `Zend_Db_Statement_Exception`.**

Regarding finding out what Exception is thrown, you could take a look at [edorian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041534/catching-exceptions-for-insert-on-duplicate-key-update-workaround-in-zf/5041609#5041609).